# $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan is not a function

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am looking to integrate BarCode scanner plugin "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" in my existing ios project. Plugin has been installed successfully but when I am calling `scan()` method. It is throwing an error

> Error: $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan is not a function. (In
>   '$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan()', '$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan' is
>   undefined)

Although `Object.getOwnPropertyNames($cordovaBarcodeScanner)` method returning "encode,decode". I do not understand where is `scan()` method gone.

Plugin working fine in newly created project not in my existing project. What could be possible reason please?

Comment: Where are you testing your app? Real device, emulator or browser?

Comment: @LeftyX I am testing in Real device and tested in emulator too, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the ngCordova lib to your project ?

If you want to use the `$cordovaBarcodeScanner` Provider, you need it. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

Otherwise just use the plugin like that: `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()`

Comment: Yes ngCordova already included in project as I am using other ngCordova plugins. I tried both but no luck. It is something related to configuration or else.